# What replaces Unsafe.copyMemory(Object, long, Object, long, long) in Java 9+?

Tags: java, performance

`Unsafe.copyMemory(Object, long, Object, long, long)` is extremely valuable to be able to quickly copy an object to an address.

Unfortunately, ever since Java 9, only primitive arrays seem to be valid for the first argument. You will get an exception for trying to use other object types:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.invalidInput(Unsafe.java:440)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.checkPrimitiveArray(Unsafe.java:560)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.checkPrimitivePointer(Unsafe.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.copyMemoryChecks(Unsafe.java:832)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory(Unsafe.java:800)
    at jdk.unsupported/sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory(Unsafe.java:573)
```

What is the replacement (with similar performance, if possible) for using this method in such a way for Java 9+?

I was thinking about doing it using `Unsafe.getLong(Object, long offset)` to read the value from an object, `Unsafe.putLong(Object, long offset, long value)`, i.e.:

```java
void copy(long dest, Object src, long srcSize) {
    long destOffset = 0L;
    while (destOffset < srcSize) {
        long value = unsafe.getLong(src, destOffset);

        long destAddress = dest + destOffset;
        unsafe.putLong(destAddress, value); // JVM crashes here

        destOffset += 8L
    }
}
```

But this is far slower than the original method.

Comment: This misfeature was removed on purpose. There is no replacement and will never be. Why do you think copying field-by-field or by longs is slower? Do you have a benchmark? What is an average size of objects you copy this way?